# iOS distribute a unique specialized personal app?

Tags: ios

has somebody an idea how to distribute a specialized personal app?
AdHoc is possible only up to 100 devices. What to do when suddenly comes 1000 people?

In this time has nearly everybody his own website, what happened when tommorow wants everybody his own app ( and is not a company with business licence )?

Thank you for any answer, idea, opinion...

Comment: Personal means just for you. If 1000 people want it, put it on the store...

Comment: Thanks, but when 1000 people wants a different app which is made only for them. It means 1000 unique specialized apps. Apple reject a unique apps.... Or not?

Comment: 2.12
Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected. https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, each of your 1000 people (clients) would need to have their own enterprise account.

Apps are different to websites though so your comparison isn't strictly accurate.

Comment: The point is that I made an app for my friend for a free - only to make her life easier. But her another friends who do the same, wants it also now. I dont want to earn on them a money( crazy or?). So 299$ only to pay an enterprice licence is for them a lot... I thought if there is not another possibilitie...

Comment: So why not release it on the store?

Comment: I read the Guidelines from Apple and I found out that in some points is it possible, that the app like this will be rejected.. But maybe is it better to try first through the AppStore...

Comment: The aim is always to make something useful. If you have a number of people who are interested that suggests it might be specialist but that there is a market for it.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion and your time! Wish a nice day and a lot of success:)